# Add Payments To Rails Ecommerce

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, e-commerce, bcrypt

I have been working on the Agile with Rails 5.1 book and looking to add a payments to a rails Ecommerce app, I currently have bcrypt installed for the admin to add new products. The customers can only access the shop page, add/remove item and checkout.

Would I need to install devise for customer authentication and use Active Merchant, Stripe, PayPal etc or add new migrations to the existing User's table for bcrypt and build the payments on that ?

Comment: not quite sure how authentication is related to payments in your app. however, you can have `User` model with multiple roles (admin, customer, etc.) and some authorization/permission mechanism or `User` and `Admin` models and separate authentication for each.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks for the reply, have replaced bcrypt with Devise and created different roles. Users can log in, add to cart and checkout, provides a real world experience.